# Does Hibernate Search's conditional indexing work with the MassIndexer API?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search with conditional indexing on one of the entity classes.  The `@Indexed` annotation for that entity specifies a custom interceptor, which prevents instances in a certain state from being indexed.

This is working perfectly as expected.  However, I notice that when I use a `MassIndexer` to reindex everything, it ignores my custom interceptor on that entity class.  I've confirmed through debug mode that the interceptor is never even invoked, and *all* instances of that entity are indexed even when they fit the criteria for being skipped.

Am I missing something?  Is there a method for reindexing in Hibernate Search that DOES utilize any custom interceptors on the entity classes?

### UPDATE

I have tried switching to the "old style" approach suggested by Sanne, using this code snippet:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
fullTextSession.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
fullTextSession.beginTransaction();

// Kill the current index
fullTextSession.purgeAll(MyEntity.class);
int batchSize = 10;
ScrollableResults results = fullTextSession.createCriteria(MyEntity.class)
        .setFetchSize(batchSize)
        .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
int index = 0;
while(results.next()) {

    // Re-index entites in batches of 10, freeing up memory after each batch
    index++;
    fullTextSession.index(results.get(0));
    if (index % batchSize == 0) {
        fullTextSession.flushToIndexes();
        fullTextSession.clear();
    }
}
fullTextSession.getTransaction().commit();
```

However, I am seeing the exact same behavior as I was with `MassIndexer`.  The conditional mapping interceptor on `MyEntity` is not invoked, and all `MyEntity` instances are indexed whether they should be or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not: [HSEARCH-1190](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSEARCH-1190).

Working on it, contributions and testers welcome!

You could use old-style indexing using a forward-only scrollable until that's fixed: [Using flushToIndexes()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-flushtoindexes)

Comment: I've updated the question, because I'm still seeing the same behavior even with the old-style approach.  Is there something else I'm missing, or are you sure that there IS a workaround for this bug?

Comment: I just noticed in the javadocs for `org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed` that the `interceptor` element is "experimental" (and therefore so is conditional indexing in general).  If you can't rely on the conditions when re-indexing, then at the very least the documentation should call this out more explicitly.  People should be aware of that limitation before they decide whether to use conditional indexing at all in production yet.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble. The reference docs state very clearly the indexing interceptor feature is experimental: we didn't know what specific issues ;) Anyway, now you can try 4.2.0.Beta2 as I resolved the problem. http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/ProgressOnHibernateSearch42TikaTextExtractionAndSortbydistance

Comment: Ah, there is an "experimental" mention in the reference manual... you are correct!  I have also confirmed that `MassIndexer` respects `EntityIndexingInterceptor` in 4.2.0.Beta2.  However, the old-style `flushToIndexes()` approach discussed above still doesn't work.  I supposed that workarounds include switching to `MassIndexer`, or replacing conditional indexing with a filter on the Lucene side or a results transformer on the Hibernate side.  Thanks for your work, Sanne!

Comment: When suggesting the "old style" I meant that since you are loading the entity it's trivial to apply any rule you might need to check, and then decide to invoked _index_ or not. Your observation is correct, the _index_ method is going to index it -  whatever the interceptor - that's by design. Created HSEARCH-1225 to clarify this! thanks for pointing these things out.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Unfortunately I did not found good solution anywhere. I tried develop own solution, but i'm not proud of it. Maybe someone can improve it.

```
int index = 0;
EntityIndexingInterceptor eii = 
        ((SearchFactoryIntegrator) fullTextSession.getSearchFactory())
        .getIndexBindingForEntity(MyEntity.class)
        .getEntityIndexingInterceptor();
while(results.next()) {
    if (eii.onAdd(results.get(0)) != IndexingOverride.SKIP){  // explit call interceptor
        index++;
        fullTextSession.index( results.get(0) ); 
        if (index % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            fullTextSession.flushToIndexes();
            fullTextSession.clear(); 
        }
    }
}
fullTextSession.flushToIndexes();
```

I was looking for simpler way to trigger interceptor but no success :(

btw.
If you look in EntityIndexingInterceptor declaration you can see:

```
//FIXME should we add onPurge and onIndex?
```